# Confirm the answer to compute the asymptotic solution to the problem

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have the following problem [image]

[image]

The solution I derived is $O(g(n))$ where $C = 1, n > 1$. Is this solution correct ?

Answer (score 1):

No. 
Hint: Your solution ($\sqrt(n) = O(log(n + 3))$ in verbose means that $\sqrt(n)$ grows as most as fast as $log(n + 3)$ $\forall n > 1$